# Can't set session manually

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm new in Laravel 5.8 and I need to set a session manually I use this code `Session::set('subset', 'yes');` but I get error how to set session manually in Laravel 5.8

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: the answer of your question is actually in the documentation of laravel 5.8 visit here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) I use ajax and I get this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the session variable with value as follows..

```
 Session::put('key','value');
```

Retrieve value using

In controller

```
 $value = Session::get('key');
```

In view

```
 {{Session::get('key')}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the global session helper which is available in laravel 5.8.

Set session simply by using

```
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

Retrieve session using

```
$value = session('key');
```